# Removing items from a sitemap

Tags: sitemap

I'm having a problem removing some unwanted links from my sitemap.

The hierarchy which we have in the sitemap is incorrect. I don't want that be like that.

Is there any way which I can change it? Please refer to the below screenshot. 
I want to remove the highlighted items from the current sitemap.

[image: screenshot of sitemap]

Comment: are you using any CMS or Frameworks ? sitemaps may generate dynamically.

Comment: From the screenshot, he generated the sitemap from a free sitemap generating website that crawls up to 500 pages from a site and puts those into a sitemap.

Comment: Nicely spotted @StephenOstermiller -  You most likely uploaded the sitemap using FTP or SFTP, most FTP clients these days include a inbuilt text editor, or load one at least. You might able to login to the FTP and right click the file and click edit.

Answer (score 3):

Sitemap files are a type of XML text file.   Open the file with a text editor, remove the section that you don't want, and re-save the file.

If you don't want the spider that crawled your site to generate that sitemap to put the pages in to begin with, you could edit your *robots.txt* file to block certain pages:

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /customer/account/login/
Disallow: /checkout/
Disallow: /about-us
```